# What is the name for the car radio SONY XR-4351 connection in the image below?

Tags: electrical, audio

[image]What is the name for the car radio SONY XR-4351 connection in the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is an XR-4351, it doesn't have a cord which goes from the connector you're showing. The XR-4351 is a vintage pull out cassette player. There should be a metal enclosure the head unit pulls in/out of which has the connector inside. The wiring/cord comes off of the enclosure. IOW: You have to have the enclosure to make it work.

Here is an image of the head unit next to the enclosure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this information, I will have to look at sourcing the cage, But thank you!!!